# window function over computed column

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, postgresql-10

I'm writing a query which looks something like this:

```sql
select parent.id,
       parent.date, 
       sum(child.amount) filter (where child.is_ok) as child_sum,
       sum(sum(child.amount) filter (where child.is_ok)) over (order by parent.date)
  from parent
  left join child on parent.id = child.parent_id
 group by parent.id, parent.date
 order by parent.date desc
```

As you can see, I'm using a window function to get a running total over `child.amount`.

The question is, is there any standard or non-standard way to reference the `child_sum` without copying its expression inside the window function `sum`?

I'm using Postgres 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT id, date, child_sum,
       sum(child_sum) over (order by date)
FROM (SELECT parent.id,
             parent.date, 
             sum(child.amount) FILTER (WHERE child.is_ok) AS child_sum
      FROM parent
      LEFT JOIN child ON parent.id = child.parent_id
      GROUP BY parent.id, parent.date
     ) AS subq
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Comment: Yeah, that is one way. The problem is I'm using ORM to do this query, so there doesn't seen to be an easy way to do a subquery here. As there doesn't seem to be a way to reference `child_sum` within the same query, I'll accept this as a right answer.

Comment: Perhaps you can define a view for the subquery, and get your ORM to use that.